# Ubuntu fails to install in FreeBSD/Bhyve

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, freebsd

Question for the FreeBSD virtualization experts. I've found some tutorials explaining how to install Ubuntu in bhyve (FreeBSD's virtualization engine) but it fails miserably after formatting the virtual disk. Did someone succeed with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS? Here is my boot script:

```
#!/bin/sh
LOADER=/usr/sbin/bhyveload
BHYVECTL=/usr/sbin/bhyvectl
FBSDRUN=/usr/sbin/bhyve
DEFAULT_MEMSIZE=2048M
DEFAULT_CPUS=2
DEFAULT_TAPDEV=tap5
DEFAULT_CONSOLE=/dev/nmdm5A
DPY="w=1024,h=768"
UEFI=/usr/local/share/uefi-firmware/BHYVE_UEFI.fd
DEVICESMAP="/home/bhyve/ubuweb/devices.map"
DEFAULT_VIRTIO_DISK="/home/bhyve/ubuweb/ubuweb.img"
DEFAULT_ISOFILE="/home/bhyve/ISO/ubuntu-16.04-server-amd64.iso"

case $1 in
  install)
    bhyvectl --vm=ubuntu --destroy
    grub-bhyve -r cd0 -m ${DEVICESMAP} -M 2048 ubuntu
    bhyve -c ${DEFAULT_CPUS} -m ${DEFAULT_MEMSIZE} -H -P -A \
        -l com1,${DEFAULT_CONSOLE} \
        -s 0:0,hostbridge \
        -s 1:0,lpc \
        -s 2:0,virtio-net,${DEFAULT_TAPDEV} \
        -s 3,ahci-cd,${DEFAULT_ISOFILE} \
        -s 4,virtio-blk,${DEFAULT_VIRTIO_DISK} \
        -s 5,fbuf,tcp=0.0.0.0:5900,$DPY \
        ubuntu
    ;;

  *)
    bhyvectl --vm=ubuntu --destroy
    grub-bhyve -r hd0,msdos1 -m ${DEVICESMAP} -M ${DEFAULT_MEMSIZE} \
            -d /grub ubuntu -n -c /dev/null
    bhyve -c ${DEFAULT_CPUS} -m ${DEFAULT_MEMSIZE} -H -P -A \
            -l com1,${DEFAULT_CONSOLE} \
            -s 0:0,hostbridge \
            -s 1:0,lpc \
            -s 2:0,virtio-net,${DEFAULT_TAPDEV} \
            -s 3,ahci-cd,${DEFAULT_ISOFILE} \
            -s 4,virtio-blk,${DEFAULT_VIRTIO_DISK} \
            -s 5,fbuf,tcp=0.0.0.0:5900,${DPY} \
            ubuntu
    ;;
esac
```

The installation program starts happily so I don't anticipate major issues with this script. I got OpenSuse up and running without any issue with a similar script. If it is relevant, the CPU is an AMD FX(tm)-6300. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I just got 16.04.3 LTS (Server) running using the [vm-bhyve](https://github.com/churchers/vm-bhyve) (a wrapper on top of bhyve, available as a port/install with `pkg install vm-bhyve grub2-bhyve`) and its basic Ubuntu template. From there, you can look in the vm's directory (wherever you specified `vm_dir` during configuration) and find the vm's log.  Inside that log, you will see what bhyve options were used.  It looks like most options are covered by vm-bhyve's config, though; maybe there is no need to use bhyve directly.

I found that during the Ubuntu install partition process, choosing the LVM option would result in the VM booting into the grub console.  But it finally worked when I chose the guided, non-LVM option.